# Are ethereum and polygon ENS synced?

Tags: polygon, ens, bridge

I want to buy myself an ENS domain, but i don't want to pay the gas fees on eth. I know that ENS is integrated on both blockchains but I can't find info if they are synced in any way. If I buy the domain in polygon is there any guarantee that 1) it will work on eth and 2) no one will be able to buy it on eth.

Answer (score 0):

[ENS does not mention Polygon as an official deployment](https://docs.ens.domains/ens-deployments). Thus, it is unlikely they are synced or there even exist a deployment that is supported on Polygon.